# Spatialite Index not matching

Tags: spatialite, spatial-index

I have a dataset containing GPS points I store in a table with a geometry column. I use the following code to populate my table.

```
CREATE TABLE STOPS_GEO 
(
stop_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
stop_desc TEXT,
stop_place TEXT,
pole_key TEXT,
stop_operator TEXT,
stop_lat DOUBLE,
stop_lon DOUBLE
);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('STOPS_GEO', 'stop_geometry', 31370, 'POINT', 2, 1);

INSERT INTO STOPS_GEO (stop_id, stop_desc, stop_place, pole_key, stop_operator, stop_lat, stop_lon)
SELECT  stop_id, stop_desc, stop_place, ('') pole_key, stop_operator, stop_lat, stop_lon
FROM STOPS_CSV
WHERE stop_lat IS NOT null AND stop_lon IS NOT null;

UPDATE STOPS_GEO SET stop_geometry = Transform(MakePoint(stop_lon, stop_lat, 4326), 31370);
```

I've created a spatial-index

```
SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('STOPS_GEO', 'stop_geometry');
```

But when I try to use the index as filter to narrow search with this kind of query no results are returned. Results are returned if I use a huge MBR Circle radius, but they are inconsistent.

```
SELECT *
FROM STOPS_GEO AS S 
WHERE S.stop_id IN
(
SELECT ROWID FROM SpatialIndex 
WHERE f_table_name='STOPS_GEO' AND search_frame=BuildCircleMbr(X(Transform(MakePoint(4.336527, 50.835705, 4326), 31370)) ,Y(Transform(MakePoint(4.336527, 50.835705, 4326), 31370)), 10, 31370)
)
```

When I have a look at the data stored in the spatial-index I've noticed the X and Y values don't add up with the position of my points.

[image: Spatial-index test results]

How come the data stored in the spatial-index is not consistent with the input-data ? Where did it all go wrong ?!

Comment: Can you show a little bit of your data? Just a point that you expect to match and a point that you don't expect to match will be enough.